C# define a long or Guid constraint for a generic type with compile-time error
Given a generic type like this, is it possible to define a long or Guid constraint that generates compile-time ristrictions for any violation?
public abstract class Typed<TId> where TId : MyConstraint // that allows only long or Guid

This question is reported to have answers, what I want is constraints that generate compile-time errors, it's 15 years since the question is asked and lots of things are changed.
Please note: a compile-time error and NOT a runtime, I already have implemented runtime solutions.
And no, multiple subs aren't going to help me.
For anyone wondering why this is needed, well an aggregate inheriting from aggregateBase with a type argument that's either long or Guid.

No, it is not possible.

Why do you want this? I can not think of implementation, that would require generic parameters, but on the other site, limit this gererics by allowing it to be just one of the two types. Maybe just put common logic (type independent) in other class and leave long logic and Guid lgoic in other classes

With an internal constructor, you could limit implementations to the same assembly. Extension methods or cast operations can be limited to specific type parameters.

Why not just implement two types? TypedIdLong and TypedIdGuid ? Add an non-generic interface or abstract base class if there need to be a common interface. What would the generic type parameter add for your use case? How is this type intended to be used?

@MichałTurczyn use cases are clear, an aggregate inheriting from a base aggregate and passes a type argument of either Guid or long for identification.

@JeremyLakeman may I have an example? apprepciate it.

@JonasH isn't going to help, this is although a solution but in my case it's an aggregate that inherits from a base aggregate.

I Don't see really understand what you mean by "aggregate that inherits from a base aggregate". But if you are trying to do stuff with generics that are not possible, chances are you should use some other design. The only commonality I can think of between long and guid is that both are commonly used as database keys, but that is not really something the c# type system cares about.

@JonasH thanks for your help. chances are throwing an exception at runtime. and yes these are database keys, my event sourcing framework remaining flexible to allow a guid or long to identify an event stream, clients fight over longs and guids you know.
this is all fine as we always find a workaround, what I don't understand is closing my question because a question being asked 15 years ago might have answers, that it doesn't, some folks behavior that needs a revisit.

I did not vote to close. But the simple answer to your question is "you can't". And it does not contain enough context or background information to propose a better approach.
